# Migrating VS2008 SSIS package (SQL Server 2008 R2) to newer machine

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ssis, operating-system, upgrade

I have an old machine with Windows XP OS. It has VS 2008 / SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on that. We have a SSIS package that we are using on the machine.

Now we want to migrate that application to a newer machine. I don't want to change the VS / SQL Server versions.

What is the best machine to migrate this combination to ?

Can I use Windows 10 or should I stick with Windows 8.1 or Windows 7?

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks more of a topic for http://serverfault.com. Also too broad and asking for opinions. Please read on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to migrate all SSIS packges from Sql server 2008 to higher version?

If so you don't need to do anything cause the SSIS packages in sql server is backward compatible

If you want to migrate from VS2008 to VS2012 or higher, you could simply open all package from newer version of VS, VS could automatically upgrade the package for you. **NOTE some of the tasks may not be upgraded successfully based on the tasks themselves**

AND **DO BACK UP ALL YOU PACKAGES BEFORE OPENNING IN HIGHER VERSION OF VS!!!**
once they have been opened in higher version of VS, most time they could not been opened from lower version of VS anymore, be **VERY CAREFUL**

And that has nothing to do with the OS, you could either use windows 7,8.1 or 10, and remember VS only has 32 bit version.